# java- Why am I getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 error in both my classes?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexing

I have this as my first class (just an excerpt) which is called Directory.java and contains a method to find a name in the directory.

```
   public boolean find(String LastName) {
      boolean inDir = false;
      LastName = LastName.toLowerCase();
      for (int i = 0; i < dir.length; i++) {
         String info = dir[i]; 
         String loweredInfo = info.toLowerCase();
         String[] splitInfo = loweredInfo.split(" "); //splits the string by space
         if (splitInfo[3].equalsIgnoreCase(LastName)) { //**ERROR HERE**
            System.out.println(info);
            inDir = true;
         }            
      }
      if (inDir == false) {
         System.out.println(LastName + " not in THIS directory\n");
      }
      return inDir;
      }
```

I have another class called DirectoryServer and here is an excerpt:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;    
public class DirectoryServer {
   public static void main(String[] args)  {
      System.out.println("Directory Server is Ready! \nCommand: find LastName | delete UCID | add\n To end, type close ");
      Directory d = new Directory("UniversityDirectoryA.txt");
      while(true) { 
         System.out.print("Enter New Command: ");
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         String myLine = scan.nextLine(); //finds out whether command is to add,find, or delete
         String[] splitInfo = myLine.split(" ");
         if (splitInfo[0].equals("close")) { //closes directory and updates directory.txt
            d.closeDirectory(); 
            break;
         }
         else if (splitInfo[0].equals("find")) {
            d.find(splitInfo[1]); //**ERROR HERE**
         }
```

When I run my DirectoryServer class, this is the output I get:

```
Enter New Command: find batra
Staff 77777 Joe Batra plumbing
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Directory.find(Directory.java:39)
    at DirectoryServer.main(DirectoryServer.java:18)
```

So it is finding the correct person (Joe Batra in this case) but then it exits out of the program due to the error.

Now if I search for a name that is not in the directory, instead of printing "not in directory," it prints the following:

```
Enter New Command: find smith
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Directory.find(Directory.java:39)
    at DirectoryServer.main(DirectoryServer.java:18)
```

I am not getting any compilation errors. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the value of `loweredInfo`?

Comment: loweredInfo looks like this: staff 77777 joe batra plumbing @marvin

Comment: Then there must be an entry in `dir` that doesn't follow that format, causing the IOOB exception

Comment: before indexing of an array splitInfo[3] check to see if the array has a length that is larger than the index.  if(splitInfo.length > 3).... else show error

Comment: I'd guess there might be entries like `.` or `..`. Print out every value of `loweredInfo` and see which one is looking different.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for us if my answer doesn't solve it?

Comment: @Aerus yes I just figured it out after you said that..one of my other classes was causing the problem because when I added a new name (add is another method in my program), it was adding commas to my text file which was causing problems. But it is working now after I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that array[3] will return the 4th item in your list, right?

```
myArray = {0,1,2,3}

myArray[3] = 3
```

You seem to have values you are not expecting. You should test your input data before assuming it's length. Try something like this...

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dir.length; i++) {
     String info = dir[i]; 
     String loweredInfo = info.toLowerCase();
     String[] splitInfo = loweredInfo.split(" "); //splits the string by space
     if(splitInfo.length == 4){
        if (splitInfo[3].equalsIgnoreCase(LastName)) { //**ERROR HERE**
            System.out.println(info);
            inDir = true;
         }
    }            
  }
```

The IndexOutOfBounds Exception could be caught and thrown, but that is not the most experinced way to handle this. Most IDEs will not prompt you to catch this error, while they may offer auto fillin for others. This is because this error tells you that something you aren't expecting to happen is happening. In your case, your String is not splitting into 4 parts like you expect.